# Using flutter_zxing leads to camera session closing automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, zxing

I'm attempting to implement real-time qr code scanning & image capturing (via a button click) using the [flutter_zxing](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zxing) package and the default flutter camera package. I'm initializing the `CameraController` variable as required in the setUp() async function, then awaiting the `startCameraProcessing();` future according to the zxing docs. Furthermore, once the controller has been initialized I start an image stream inside which I try to read a QR code if possible (again following the zxing docs).

The issue is that although the camera preview shows up normally, placing a QR code in the camera's view doesn't seem to do anything. While checking the logs, I noticed the following lines:

```
I/Camera  ( 9264): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  ( 9264): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  ( 9264): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/Camera  ( 9264): startPreviewWithImageStream
I/Camera  ( 9264): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  ( 9264): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  ( 9264): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  ( 9264): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/Camera  ( 9264): CameraCaptureSession onClosed
W/System  ( 9264): A resource failed to call release.
```

These seem to indicate that the camera session has been closed, correct? How would this happen if I didn't explicitly initiate it?

I've also noticed that clicking the capture image button, the app crashes with:

```
I/Camera  ( 9264): sending capture request
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264): FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264): Process: com.example.camera, PID: 9264
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CaptureRequest contains unconfigured Input/Output Surface!
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest.convertSurfaceToStreamId(CaptureRequest.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1212)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.capture(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1084)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.capture(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.takePictureAfterPrecapture(Camera.java:644)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.onConverged(Camera.java:228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.CameraCaptureCallback.process(CameraCaptureCallback.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.CameraCaptureCallback.onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureCallback.java:161)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$1.lambda$onCaptureProgressed$2$CameraCaptureSessionImpl$1(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:692)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.-$$Lambda$CameraCaptureSessionImpl$1$7mSdNTTAoYA0D3ITDxzDJKGykz0.run(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9264):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Could this also be caused due to the camera session having been closed? Any ideas on how the session is being terminated?

Code:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_zxing/flutter_zxing.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized so that `availableCameras()`
  // can be called before `runApp()`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
  final cameras = await availableCameras();

  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TakePictureScreen(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// A screen that allows users to take a picture using a given camera.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TakePictureScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.camera,
  });

  final CameraDescription camera;

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  CameraController? _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setUp();
  }

  Future<void> setUp() async {
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.high,
    );

    await startCameraProcessing();

    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller!.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }

      setState(() {});

      _controller!.startImageStream((image) async {
        CodeResult result = await processCameraImage(image);
        if (result.isValidBool) {
          debugPrint(result.textString);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.stopImageStream();
    stopCameraProcessing();
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Take a picture')),
      // You must wait until the controller is initialized before displaying the
      // camera preview. Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner until the
      // controller has finished initializing.
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return CameraPreview(_controller!);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await _controller!.takePicture();

            if (!mounted) return;

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(
                  // Pass the automatically generated path to
                  // the DisplayPictureScreen widget.
                  imagePath: image.path,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A widget that displays the picture taken by the user.
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({super.key, required this.imagePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Display the Picture')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Image.file(File(imagePath)),
    );
  }
}
```